# Concurent dictionary locking

Tags: c#, concurrency, concurrentdictionary

I am currently reading code delivered by our extern person and I don't understand this part of the code:

```
    private ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, Person> users = new ConcurrentDictionary<Int64, Person>();
    private Dictionary<String, Int64> connectionIndex = new Dictionary<String, Int64>();

    public Boolean AddNewUser(Int64 userId, Person user) {
        Boolean added = false;
        lock (users) {

            if (users.Select(X=>X.Key==userId).Count()>0)
            {
                Person usrtmp = new Person();
                users.TryRemove(userId,out usrtmp)
            }
                added = users.TryAdd(userId, user);
                if (added)
                {
                    connectionIndex.Add(user.ConnectionId, userId);
                }

        }
        return added;   
    }
```

Why "users concurrent dictionary" is locked before any operation on that dictionary is done? Is it necessary? From my point of view is lock statement unnecessary because ConcurrentDictionary contains thread-safe operations. Am I right?
Also, I know about "performance issue" when you use .Count() or Key, Value operations on ConcurrentDictionary. Is it LINQ statement OK in this point of view?

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why "users concurrent dictionary" is locked before any operation on that dictionary is done? Is it necessary?

The lock is certainly necessary given how they're using it.  They're performing multiple operations on multiple different dictionaries, and it's important that no other thread interact with either dictionary in any way while that is happening.  Doing that requires a `lock`.

The only way you could remove the lock is if you get to a point where the only usage of a shared data structure is *one single* method call on a single concurrent dictionary.  Without knowing the exact requirements we can't know if that's possible, but if both dictionaries are needed, then it certainly isn't.

Now, given that you have put yourself in a position where you always need to lock over all access to the concurrent dictionary, there's no reason to use a concurrent dictionary and not a regular dictionary; you've already made the decision to use your own synchronization.

> From my point of view is lock statement unnecessary because ConcurrentDictionary contains thread-safe operations. Am I right?

No.  For starters, the non-concurrent dictionary cannot be accessed without a lock

> Also, I know about "performance issue" when you use .Count() or Key, Value operations on ConcurrentDictionary. Is it LINQ statement OK in this point of view?

It's a *horrible* idea for lots of reasons.  It's trying to do a linear search through a dictionary to see if a key exists.  You should *never* be doing that.  You should be using `ContainsKey`.  Additionally, there's just no point if checking if the key is there before trying to remove it, you can just try to remove it and see what happens.  It's also completely unsafe if you weren't already locking, as someone else could be changing the dictionary while you're iterating it, and it can change after you've searched it, making checking before doing anything pointless, as you can't assume that the thing that you just checked is true.